# Connect routers in gns3

Tags: router, gns3

I have a topology of three routers connected with each other.

[image]

The problem is that it has a different network address on two directly connected ports of router R1 and R2. So I am not able to ping R1 from R2.

Is there any way to make them communicate?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

R1 and R2 are not in the same subnet. R1 is in 131.43.43.1/27 and R2 is in 131.44.44.2/27. Put R2 into 131.43.43.2/27 and it should work.

You already wrote, that the IP ranges do not overlap. So, there really is no way for the devices to communicate with each other if their IP ranges are out of reach of each other. You would have to set a router in between these 2 devices to translate between the 2 networks. Other solution would be to use NAT to transform the source and/or destination IPs as they go out of an interface. But this would be a very stupid solution that is difficult to maintain/troubleshoot. Is there a reason why you built the setup like this?

Comment: " Is there a reason why you built the setup like this?"- It is a part of a corporate project.

Comment: So then to answer your question: No they cannot comunicate. You have to adjust one of the IPs to ensure, they are both within the same subnet. This is how the IP protocol is intended to be used.